# Django Urls - Template Issue {% url '' %}

Tags: python, html, django, python-3.x, django-urls

When I started Django I used 1.11 and since then upgraded to 2.0. My URLs worked and had no problems and I would imagine something has been updated but I keep going over the documentation and I can't see where the issue is. From what I've seen my URL in template is correct, even though I have also tried with '' and still get the same issue.

```
NoReverseMatch at /admin/dashboard
Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/dashboard
Django Version: 2.2.6
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Exception Location: /home/bridgetsarah/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 673
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.5.2
Python Path:    
['/home/bridgetsarah/voyage/bridgetsarah',
 '/usr/lib/python35.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.5',
 '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload',
 '/home/bridgetsarah/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
Server time:    Fri, 25 Oct 2019 19:26:43 +0000
```

```
      <ul>
24      <li> <i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i>  <a href="#"> Dashboard </a> </li>
25      <li><i class="fas fa-tasks"></i>  <a href='#'> Projects </a> </li>
26      <li><i class="fas fa-users"></i> <a href="{% url client %}"> Clients </a> </li>
27      <li><i class="fas fa-server"></i><a href='#'> Servers </a> </li>
28    </ul>  
29
```

```
from django.urls import include, path , re_path
from django.conf.urls import  include, url
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView
from voyage.views import login_invalid, dashboard, client


app_name = 'voyage'

urlpatterns = [
   
    
    # Clients---------------------------------- #
    path('admin/client', views.client, name='client'),]
```

```
def client(request):
    return render(request, 'admin/client/client.html', context)
```

What can I try next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `{% url "client" %}` - the name must be in quotes.

Note, this changed all the way back in Django 1.5 (in 2012); this definitely wouldn't have worked in version 1.11.

Comment: Thanks for answering but still same issue even though I tried doing that also :(

Comment: @bridgetsarah if you make the change that Daniel suggested you'll get a *different* error message, e.g. `Reverse for 'client' not found.` You solve that by including the namespace. You have `app_name = 'voyage'` in the `urls.py`, so it should be `{% url "voyage:client" %}`

Comment: Thank you for this! It does work, sorry I've not tried using the app_name part before, I'll revise on this :)